# How to upload/update file by FileStream and ResumableUploader in C#

Tags: c#, filestream, gdata, google-docs-api, google-drive-api

I wanna upload/update file by System.IO.FileStream in Google Documents List API(C#)?

I use two way below: Google.GData.Client.ResumableUpload.ResumableUploader
   (1) public void UpdateAsync(Authenticator authentication, AbstractEntry payload, object userData)
   (2) public void UpdateAsync(Authenticator authentication, Uri resumableUploadUri, Stream payload, string contentType, object userData)

(1) Success.
(2) Failed with 403 Forbidden or another...

So, does someone have any sample code about (2)?

My Code for (2):
This code is edited by sample code from **Claudio Cherubino**, and it's work for uploading file stream to Google Documents(Drive). But the file(DocumentEntry)'s name show 'Untitled' on page of Google Drive. It seems 'slug' not work. Do I miss some important settings?

```
Google.GData.Documents.DocumentsService conn =
new Google.GData.Documents.DocumentsService("TestSend");
conn.setUserCredentials("UserName", "UserPass");

string path = @"D:\test_file\test.exe"; 

Google.GData.Client.ResumableUpload.ResumableUploader send =
new Google.GData.Client.ResumableUpload.ResumableUploader();
send.AsyncOperationCompleted += new Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventHandler(
    delegate(object sender,
        Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("File Send Done");
    }
);

System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(path, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite);

send.InsertAsync(
    new Google.GData.Client.ClientLoginAuthenticator("TestSend", "writely", this._DiskConn.Credentials),
    new System.Uri("https://docs.google.com/feeds/upload/create-session/default/private/full?v=3"),
    fs,
    "application/octet-stream",
    System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path),
    new object()
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
DocumentsService service = new DocumentsService("MyDocumentsListIntegration-v1");
ClientLoginAuthenticator authenticator = new ClientLoginAuthenticator(APPLICATION_NAME, ServiceNames.Documents, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

string slug = "Legal contract";
MediaFileSource mediaSource = new MediaFileSource("c:\\contract.txt", "text/plain");
Uri createUploadUrl = new Uri("https://docs.google.com/feeds/upload/create-session/default/private/full?v=3");

ResumableUploader ru = new ResumableUploader();
ru.InsertAsync(authenticator, createUploadUrl, mediaSource.GetDataStream(), mediaSource.ContentType, slug, new object());
```

Comment: It's work! I replace 'mediaSource.GetDataStream()' to 'new FileStream("[file path]", FileMode.Open)', and I found the file on Google Drive. But a little strange, the DocumentEntry named 'Untitled' in the Google Drive, the slug can't work normally. I upload my post with my new code.